# Microsoft Graph Security API - Issue with https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/security/tiIndicators

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-security, azure-sentinel

I am trying to use Microsoft graph API threat Indicators API based on Azure sentinel recommended way of integrating threat intelligence sources for IOC ingestion to Sentinel Instance. I perform the following steps in linux curl to test the functionality :

Get the OAuth token from Microsoft using :

```
curl -X POST -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[myClientId]&client_secret=[myAppSecret]&scope=openid profile ThreatIndicators.ReadWrite.OwnedBy' https://login.microsoftonline.com/[myTenantId]/oauth2/token
```

Using the received bearer token calling the following API: `curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer [access token]" https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/security/tiIndicators`

I am receiving below mentioned error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "########################",
      "date": "2019-12-19T07:41:51"
    }
  }
```

Anybody has Idea how to use this ? Main motive is to use graph API POST query to insert threat indicators in Azure Sentinel

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `resource` rather than `scope` in request body for V1.0 token endpoint.

```
curl -X POST -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[myClientId]&client_secret=[myAppSecret]&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com' https://login.microsoftonline.com/[myTenantId]/oauth2/token
```

**OR** (V2.0 token endpoint as below)

```
curl -X POST -d 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=[myClientId]&client_secret=[myAppSecret]&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' https://login.microsoftonline.com/[myTenantId]/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

Comment: @DEEPANSHUMARWAH No problem:)